# Partial error of special character presentation

Tags: c#, html, character-encoding, iis-7.5

I have a weird error on the page that just appeared for no particular reason and I can't figure out what is wrong.

The Swedish characters å ä and ö when written i html don't get displayed correctly while same characters coming from the CMS system gets displayed correctly.

The solution is a EPiServer CMS based .net web application and when rendering the startpage all texts that come from EPiServer (editor added) is displayed correctly and viewing the source I see that these texts like the text "Sök start" is rendered as is and displayed correctly.

However in the masterpage I have some static html written like

```
<span>Stäng</span>
```

And that gets printed like

```
<span>STÃ„NG</span>
```

How is that possible? And as I said I had this working before and I can't really figure out why it stopped working all of the sudden. Is there any settings in IIS or something like that that can affect this?

The charset is set to utf-8, the globalization in web.config looks like this

```
<globalization culture="sv-SE" uiCulture="sv" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8"
```

The files is in utf-8 format.